# How to set download location with FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use `FolderBrowserDialog` to select the location where a file will be downloaded. This is the code for selecting a folder.

```
Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I just need to know how to take directory that appears in the textbox and have the file get downloaded to there. Here is the code for the download.

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download1516.mediafire.com/wtzr4h1b37zg/ptzcffq933e87c8/sword_custom.png", "C:\Users\Administrator")
```

What would I need to replace "C:\Users\Administrator" with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    Dim URL As String = "http://download1516.mediafire.com/wtzr4h1b37zg/ptzcffq933e87c8/sword_custom.png"
    Dim SaveFile As String = "sword_custom.png"

    With FolderBrowserDialog1
        If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBox1.Text = .SelectedPath
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(URL, IO.Path.Combine(.SelectedPath, SaveFile))
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to download something like a .jar would the code be the same?

Comment: @Manny42601: Obviously the URL and filename would change in the first two lines, but otherwise it would work.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'm taking a guess that it might be because you just included code in your answer, no explanation.