# Download a file and choose its location via FolderbrowserDialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to download a file and to be able to choose its location[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOUTs.png)

Here is the code I made

in "use of the directory", that's where I define a directory, but I want to be able to choose it via "FolderbrowserDialog"

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Please take your time to familiarize yourself with the site by taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), reading up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), going through [this brilliant question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and lastly, understanding how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, your question lacks your attempt. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2

Specifically:

```
if(result == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        openFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        try
        {
            // Output the requested file in richTextBox1.
            Stream s = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(s, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
            s.Close();    

            fileOpened = true;

        } 
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while attempting to load the file. The error is:" 
                            + System.Environment.NewLine + exp.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
            fileOpened = false;
        }
```

Comment: I had seen it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657003/how-to-set-download-location-with-folderbrowserdialog